# Shape.Top and Shape.Left Issues

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that looks at the position of a line that a user can edit.  The purpose of editing this line is to get rough measurements from a plot plan which works so far.  I'm working on making it much more interactive by recording measured positions as well.

Here's the issue.  When this shape (a connector elbow) is on the cabinet and the access point it records its position in points using shape.top and shape.left (code below).  When I resize this line to put the access point end on another access point, the cabinet position changes as well even though it didn't move.  I did notice that the scale height and width changed on the drawing but I can't figure out why that would affect the initial point.

It's worth noting that as you rotate the elbow connector the value of width and height rotate.  That means sometimes height is up and down and sometimes its the value you'd expect width to be.  Still the left position only stays constant when the connector is rotated 180 degrees.

Is there a relation between scale height/width and the top/left value?

```
Sub Measure()

Set sp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Measurement")

Msgbox(sp.Top & "//" & sp.Left)

end sub
```

Edit: So I realize I mentioned a lot about the program, the real problem is why do the top left measurements change despite the top left staying stationary on the screen? And only in the 270/90 rotation (happens automatically depending how you drag the line)

Add Screen Shots (Measurements are Top then left)
[This is the first screen shot with a 270 rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCK7R.jpg)
[This is the second, notice the top left stayed stationary but the points changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UTn7.jpg)
This next group is with a 180/0 rotation (shape auto rotates, otherwise I would just lock it and be done).
[Rotated 180 first screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJiOU.jpg)
[Rotated 180 second screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuIzp.jpg)

Comment: A couple of screenshots along with corresponding outputs would be pretty useful here.  Might help also to explain "cabinet", "access point" since we don't know what you're looking  at.

Comment: Refer to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908312/vb-rotate-line-about-a-point/52915518#52915518)

Comment: @TimWilliams  Added the screen shots.

Comment: @Dy.Lee Please see the additional info.

Comment: Please, Insert image not image  link. It is more easy to  understand  your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I sympathized with your problem recognition and I did not understand this phenomenon, but after testing, it seems that the original coordinates are preserved even if the figure is rotated. This is because even if the rotation is performed again, the rotation is performed by the original coordinate value. If you artificially align the position, the coordinates appear to move accordingly. I tested it as follows.

```
Sub Measure()
Dim rngT As Range
Dim sp As Shape
Set sp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Measurement")

'MsgBox (sp.Top & "//" & sp.Left)
Set rngT = Range("k" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
rngT = sp.Top
rngT.Offset(, 1) = sp.Left
End Sub

Sub test()
    Dim sp As Shape
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim vDB
    Dim i As Integer, t As Single, l As Single
    Dim r As Integer
    vDB = Range("k2", Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    For i = 1 To r
        t = vDB(i, 1)
        l = vDB(i, 2)
        Set sp = Ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, l, t, 10, 10)
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I feel like we may still have a disconnect on what I'm doing (my fault).  The shape is a measuring tape in my program.  The user puts one end on the cabinet and one end on the access point and it gives the distance.  The part that's giving me fits is that when you stretch further to the right or left instead of up or down the object rotates.  When rotation is 90 or 270 the coordinates on the stationary side shift.  I'm not sure how this code identifies that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out guys.

So in orientation 0 or 180 the Shape.top and Shape.Left give accurate consistent measurements.

In the 90 or 270 the top and left have to be adjusted to give accurate consistent measurements.

The code is Shape.Top-((Shape.Width-Shape.Height)/2) and Shape.Left+((Shape.Width-Shape.Height)/2)
(NOTE: THIS ADJUSTMENT ONLY APPLIES WHEN OBJECT IS ROTATED 90 or 270//Shape.Rotation)

Also, the shape used here is an elbow connector